# Umbraco Form v8 conditional questions not working

Tags: umbraco, umbraco8

Using Umbraco 8 with Forms 8.7.6, when I try to add a conditional question to a form it never works and there is no error.

If I change InsertUmbracoFormWithTheme.cshtml to include scripts I get the error:

'Umbraco Forms requires a validation framework to run, please read documentation for possible options'.

Does anyone have any idea how to get conditional questions to work on Forms 8?